# Extended overseas travel qualify for a Special Enrollment Period in USA?

Tags: health-care, usa

I'm a United States citizen (California resident) that has been traveling as a tourist outside the United States for the past 1.5 years.

I'm now back in Ohio to visit my parents for two months. I need healthcare coverage during these two months.

It's no longer the Open Enrollment Period. Do I qualify for a SEP? And if not, what are my options for getting healthcare coverage during these two months that also satisfies the conditions of the ACA so I don't have to pay the penalty for not having coverage during these two months? I don't qualify for medicare or medicaid.

Comment: This question looks more on topic for Travel.SE